# How do I get the dom node of a component in Svelte?

Tags: svelte, svelte-3

Say I render the following Dialog:

```
let dialog;

<MyDialog bind:this={dialog}/>
```

I want to position this dialog (using `afterUpdate` lifecycle function I guess). However, `dialog` is not a dom element. When I log it, it will look something like:

```
MyDialog {$$: {…}, left: 785, $set: ƒ, $capture_state: ƒ, $inject_state: ƒ}
$$: {fragment: {…}, ctx: Array(1), props: {…}, update: ƒ, not_equal: ƒ, …}
$capture_state: () => {…}
$inject_state: $$props => {…}
$set: $$props => {…}
someExportedProp: (...)
__proto__: SvelteComponentDev
```

How can I access its dom in order to position it?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

`MyDialog` is not a DOM element, it is a Svelte component. And so, it's what you get when you `bind:this` on it: a Svelte component.

You only get a DOM element when binding to an actual element:

```html
<div bind:this={el} />
```

If you need access to the DOM of `MyDialog` from its consumer (parent) component, you need to proxy it from the `MyDialog` component.

`MyDialog.svelte`

```html
<script>
  export let el
</script>

<div class="dialog" bind:this={el}>
  <slot />
</div>
```

`App.svelte`

```html
<script>
  import MyDialog from './MyDialog.svelte'

  let dialog

  $: console.log(dialog) // here, DOM element!
</script>

<MyDialog bind:el={dialog}>
  Hello!
</MyDialog>
```

That being said, I would think twice before leaking DOM elements outside of component. It kinda breaks encapsulation, which often ends up complicating your life... Maybe you can think of a better solution to control your dialog position without giving direct access to the innards of the component to the consumer?

**EDIT**

To move with props...

Props are "reactive", their value is automatically reflected in the DOM by the framework, so you don't need to run a function to move things. You can just declare what you want. This is the preferred style with these declarative frameworks.

```html
<script>
  export let top
  export let left

  $: style = `top: ${top}px; left: ${left}px`
</script>

<div class="dialog" {style}>
  <slot />
</div>
```

If you need too, you can still run some code when props change (imperatively) with [reactive blocks](https://svelte.dev/docs#3_$_marks_a_statement_as_reactive):

```html
<script>
  export let top
  export let left

  let el

  // reactive block will rerun each time el, top, or left changes
  $: if (el) {
    el.style.top = top + 'px'
    el.style.left = left + 'px'
  }
</script>

<div class="dialog" bind:this={el}>
  <slot />
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. Could you give me an example of a better solution? Maybe export a function then instead of the dom node?

Comment: Depends on what you really want to do when you say "position", but I think what I would do would probably be to have something like a `position` prop on the `MyDialog` component, and apply the effect to the DOM element from there, from the inside. This way, if the DOM / CSS of your dialog component evolves, you only have a single centralized place that you need to adapt.

Comment: How do I move the dialog (e.g. with dom top/left style attributes) by changing a props that would be exported? I see with an exported function, where I can give it some coordinates and I execute Dom operations to position the dialog; but I don't see how with your idea of exporting just one prop. How do you execute the Dom operations when that prop changes?

Comment: One prop can be an object, an array... It was just an example, the point was that it's often desirable to abstract the inside of a component behind a limited API, instead of exposing whole bits of it, and then you're stuck when you want to change those bits... I've added some examples of how I would move an element with props.

Comment: Man I just wanted to take a few seconds of your time if you had any, but you write me a whole edit. You're an awesome human:) thank you!